# Free alternative to World Machine

Tags: windows, gratis, 3d, game-development

[World Machine](http://www.world-machine.com/) is software for creating terrains (mostly for games).

Is there a free or open source alternative to this that will run on Windows and the licence will give me the ability to use the end result in a commercial product?

It needs to support HD resolutions (at least 1080p).

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Blender](https://www.blender.org/) sounds like it might be of interest for you. The software is based on a [GNU General Public License v2 or later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Version_2) and you can download it on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Comment: I have heard of blender and checking up tutorials on it yes. But World machine is kind of a specialized tool for terrain building

Answer (score 2):

i haven't found any free ones but i have found one that is very cheap compared to World machine https://starscenesoftware.com/fractscape.html